# Exception in Constructor Injection : No default constructor found

Tags: spring

I am trying constructor injection in Configuration class but
I am getting below excetion

```
by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.raju.sp.config.JPAConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42ae443e]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.raju.sp.config.JPAConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42ae443e.<init>()
```

My Code is as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {
    private final Environment env;
    @Autowired
    public JPAConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
    //................
}
```

But below code works

```
@Autowired
private  Environment env;
```

One more thing , Constructor Injection is working with rest controllers and other repositories.

Edit : If I add default constructor

```
public JPAConfiguration() {
   this(null);
}
```

then my Environment object will be null, If I add

```
public JPAConfiguration() {
}
```

then compilation error will be generated for final field.

Comment: Try adding one: public JPAConfiguration() { this(null); }

Comment: As the exception says, have you tried adding a default constructor for JPAConfiguration?

Comment: Add default no arg constructor `public JPAConfiguration() {
}` and remove `final` keyword for the `Environment`

Comment: Which spring version are you using? Configuration classes are a bit special as they are processed different then other components. Next to that earlier versions of spring (or actually cglib) require for classes to have a default constructor (this is only the case where class based proxies are needed).

Comment: Spring version is 4.2.3.